# Glyph images won't change colors

Tags: swift, uicolor, glyph

**Problem**: I have three glyphs from the same site (icons8.com) and when I try to set them to the same color, only 1 works properly.

*In-Depth*:
So I am attempting to get some glyphs to change colors. Some work, and some don't.

Here you can see that the glyphs are setting properly to a "yellow" tint
[image]

But then when I go to a different view that calls the same color procedure, it doesn't work. The glyphs stay black on the coffee and beer sign (the two that do not work), but the soccer ball sets properly. Reminder, all are being set to yellow.
[image]

This is the code I am using the set the glyph color in the cell within the normal `cellForRowAt`.

```
    cell.iconView.backgroundColor = eventAnnotation.markerTintColor
    cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: eventAnnotation.imageName ?? "")
    cell.iconImageView.tintColor = eventAnnotation.glyphTintColor
```

Here is the view that I am using the create the markers.

```
class EventMarkerView: MKMarkerAnnotationView {
override var annotation: MKAnnotation? {
    willSet {
        guard let eventAnnotation = newValue as? EventAnnotation else { return }
        canShowCallout = true
        calloutOffset = CGPoint(x: -5, y: 5)
        rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

        markerTintColor = eventAnnotation.markerTintColor
        glyphTintColor = eventAnnotation.glyphTintColor
        //glyphText = String(event.discipline.first!)
        if let imageName = eventAnnotation.imageName {
            glyphImage = UIImage(named: imageName)
        } else {
            glyphImage = nil
        }


        let detailLabel = UILabel()
        detailLabel.numberOfLines = 3
        detailLabel.font = detailLabel.font.withSize(12)
        detailLabel.text = eventAnnotation.subtitle
        detailCalloutAccessoryView = detailLabel

    }
}
```

}

I will also attach the different sets of glyphs I am using.

["Beer". doesn't work](https://icons8.com/icon/set/beer/ios-glyphs) .

["Soccer ball outline". Does work](https://icons8.com/icon/set/soccer/ios-glyphs) .

["Cafe". doesn't work](https://icons8.com/icon/set/coffe/ios-glyphs) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer eventually. I had to force the image (note the second line) to always use my template.

```
    cell.iconView.backgroundColor = eventAnnotation.markerTintColor
    cell.iconImageView.image = UIImage(named: eventAnnotation.imageName ?? "")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysTemplate)
    cell.iconImageView.tintColor = eventAnnotation.glyphTintColor
```

Here is the apple documentation for [.withRenderingMode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624153-withrenderingmode).

Comment: You can also set this property in the xcassets folder of your project. Select the image group (the one that contains all resolutions) and use the menu on the right.